# Is there a way to add variables in pubspec.yaml file?

Tags: flutter, yaml

The final goal is to fetch the version name from a 'version.properties' file and set it as the value of 'version' in the pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: Have you check https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv

Comment: It will allow us to use environment variables in dart code but how to use those in yaml file ?